# Как убрать вывод ошибок при запуске команды?

Tags: bash, linux

Например, команда:

```
$ grep -lr "sample" .
```

помимо печати файлов, в которых содержится строка "sample", выводит ошибки, загромождающие вывод.

*grep: <...>: Нет такого файла или каталога*
*grep: <...>: Нет такого файла или каталога*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать, встроенные опции команды (согласно справке):

```
$ grep -lsr "sample" .
```

а можно перенаправить вывод ошибок в никуда:

```
$ grep -lr "sample" . 2>/dev/null
```